# Is there a way to "GET" a csv like information in a website using only Vue.js?

Tags: csv, vue.js

I'm trying to "get" the information in this website: http://nestlegremio.ddns.net:8003/local/people-counter/.api?export-csv&date=20181126&res=30m using only vue.js http

```
this.$http.get('http://nestlegremio.ddns.net:8003/local/people-counter/.api?export-csv&date=20181126&res=30m').then(response => {
    if (response.body.length === 0) {
      console.log('error')
    } else {
      console.log(response.body)
    }
  })
```

but I'm getting the console error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://nestlegremio.ddns.net:8003/local/people-counter/.api?export-csv&date=20181126&res=30m' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are facing here comes from the fact the the server your are trying to get the file from does not allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*).

Putting is simply, you site (e.g. running on http://localhost:3003/) is trying to access http://nestlegremio.ddns.net:8003/.

- When a web browser tries to access a resource that doesn't reside on
  the same domain (http://localhost:3003/), it does a first query to
  the web server with *OPTIONS* to get CORS info from the server.
- If the server does not say CORS is enabled for this domain, then the
  browser won't run the request and throw the error message you saw.

The solution here is:

- If you **have access** to this given we server, is to allow CORS on it, if you want to rely only on client-side code.
- If you **don't have access** to the server, you will have to **build some server code** to retrieve your data from the given url, then to give it back to your Vue.js code. Http calls done from server-side code are not impacted by CORS.

[Here](https://blog.jscrambler.com/understanding-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) is a more detailed explanation on this topic.

Comment: and if I don't have access to the server to allow CORS? What can I do?

Comment: In that case the only way is to build a server hosted on the same address as you web app, which will get data from your given url, give it back to your vue app. Updated my answer with details.

Comment: So... there's no way to do this only with vue.js :( hahah